# How to add active class to wp_get_archives

Tags: wordpress, archive

How to add active class to the wordpress: `<?php wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>` generated output.

Answer (score 0):

> You can Add the CSS Selector like this by following the steps below:

**Step 1:**

Put the following function in your `functions.php`

```
function wpse_62509_current_month_selector( $link_html ) {
    $current_month = date("F Y");
    if ( preg_match('/'.$current_month.'/i', $link_html ) )
        $link_html = preg_replace('/<li>/i', '<li class="current-month">', $link_html );
    return $link_html;
}
```

And then add the following line just before calling `wp_get_archives()`

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_62509_current_month_selector' );
```

You might also want to remove the filter after calling `wp_get_archives()` so that it doesn't mess with other `wp_get_archives()` or `get_archives_link()` function calls.

```
remove_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_62509_current_month_selector' );
```

This will make the CSS selector for the Current Month. Hope so this will help you.

Comment: Hello and thank you for reply,
unfortunately it seems do not work for me, I’ve also tested with a clean WP install using “Twenty Sixteen Theme”.